# Obtaining a users subscriptions via Shopify App Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Can the App proxy be used to pass through various ID's for a separate backend rails app?

I have the case where we've implemented a subscription system in a separate rails app, but we want to show the user their subscriptions from Shopify. To do this I would like to add an app proxy on Shopify, such as:

Proxy Url: subscriptions.com/api/customers/subscriptions
Proxy Path: /a/customers

But I'd like to be able to proxy /a/customers/:customer_id/subscriptions, maybe even /a/customers/:customer_id/subscriptions/:id (for a show subscription liquid response), so concatenating the ids into the url is my main goal.

On the rails side I can easily extract the path_prefix from the params, its a matter of how Shopify is matching the Proxy Paths I guess.

Is this at all possible? Or is there another way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra path components get appended to the Proxy URL. The [Shopify Application Proxy](http://api.shopify.com/app_proxy.html) documentation even provides an example showing this in the Proxy Request section.

So for you example, where the proxy url is `http://subscriptions.com/api/customers/subscriptions` and the proxy path is `/a/customers` then a request to `/a/customers/:customer_id/subscriptions` will be proxied to `http://subscriptions.com/api/customers/subscriptions/:customer_id/subscriptions`

So it sounds like the proxy request is already exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed the details in that section.